# Relation that is both Symmetric and Asymmetric.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I was asked on a test to find the number of relations on a set with 10 elements  which is both symmetric and asymmetric.

Now since any element of the type

$$ (a,b) \quad  where \quad b \neq a $$ cannot exist in such a relation (I think).

This problem essentially reduces to the statement whether a relation which only has elements of the type $ (a,a)$ (elements found on the main diagonal of the matrix form of R) is a relation which is both symmetric and asymmetric?

Comment: You seem to be confusing *antisymmetric* and *asymmetric*. What you have is true if the question had asked about relations that are both *antisymmetric* and symmetric. As you've stated the question (being about *asymmetric* relations), there is only one possible relation. (the empty relation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for any such $R$, you can't have any $(a,a) \in R$ since that would go against asymmetry (If $(a,a) \in R$, then by asymmetry, $(a,a) \not \in R$ ... so we can't have $(a,a)$!)

The only relation that works is the empty relation, i.e. $R=\{ \}$, since if *any* $(a,b) \in R$, we must have (by symmetry) $(b,a) \in R$, but we also must have (by asymmetry) $(b,a) \in R$. Since we can't have both, we can't have *any* $(a,b) \in R$.

Comment: Antisymmetry means that $(a.b) \in R \land (b,a) \in R \Rightarrow b = a$. If antisymmetry was against reflexiveness then we couldn't have order relations.

Comment: @chelivery Correct ... but the OP asked about asymmetry, not anti-symmetry.

Comment: @chelivery The problem asked about *asymmetry*, not about *antisymmetry*. These are two different terms

Comment: Oh, damn: my bad. Of course.

Comment: No problem: easily confused! :)